# Apache nifi jolt transform to get only particular key and value

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am very new to Nifi. In Nifi using JoltTransformJson I need to convert following input to below output: Can someone please provide the Jolt specification. I have tried several ways to do this but could not get the same output.

Input

```
{
  "myOps": {
    "Ops1": {
      "type": "software",
      "url": "url-software"
    },
    "Ops2": {
      "type": "hardware",
      "url": "url-hardware"
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
   {
      "type": "software",
      "url": "url-software"
    },
   {
      "type": "hardware",
      "url": "url-hardware"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jolt for this. You can use the `EvaluateJsonPath` processor with a JsonPath expression of `$.myOps.*` which will return a valid JSON array containing the two objects you're looking for. [JsonPath.com](https://jsonpath.com/) is a good resource for evaluating & debugging JsonPath expressions.

If you have a requirement to avoid the wrapping `[]` (although that's valid JSON), you can use `ReplaceText` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "myOps": {
        "Ops*": {
          "@": "[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```